# C++/SDL threading - events break down

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I have a Snake game in-development (up at https://github.com/RobotGymnast/Gingerbread/tree/eventThreaded). Initially, everything (graphics, events, game logic update, physics) were called from a "main" thread. Then I started multithreading (using boost threads). It's been pretty straightforward, but I recently split the graphics display logic into a new thread, which allocated the screen object in its local stack space. Then I split my event-detection and event-handling logic into a new thread. Then my screen stopped appearing. Judging by my command-line output, everything still worked fine, just the screen stopped appearing. It turned out it was hanging on my SDL_SetVideoMode() call.

I fixed this by allocating my screen object in the "main" thread, and passing in a reference to the graphics thread. For some reason, allocating the screen object in a new thread from the event logic was creating problems.

Since this fix, the event-detection and event-handling no longer works. The event checks are still being made, e.g. SDL_PollEvent(), but they're not picking up any events at all (keyboard, mouse, etc.).

My suspicion is that SDL might do some behind-the-scenes thread syncing, but I've been using boost threads. Could this be a problem? SDL threads are rather restrictive, and I'd rather not switch.

Anybody had this issue before? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about SDL, but on several windowing subsystems (I believe on both X and Win32), you cannot modify ANYTHING related to a graphics object or widget, except from the thread which initially created that graphics object/widget.

It doesn't look like (to my limited 10 second google search) SDL abstracts that bit from you -- you'd need to only modify graphics related objects from the thread that created them. To do otherwise is to invite strange behavior.

Comment: That's what I was doing originally; the only way to fix it was to allocate the screen in the main thread and pass it into the graphics thread

Comment: @Robot: Then you'll have to do your graphics related work on the main thread. That's platform specific. Win32 (I believe) doesn't have a restriction like that, but other windowing systems might.

Comment: Yikes, thanks for the heads-up! I'm running on Windows, and it wasn't multithreaded when I switched from my Gentoo box. Switched now.

Answer (score 3):

Graphics display logic should almost always be in the main thread, due to some technical considerations on various platforms.

Similarly, the event handling (at least at the low level) should be in the main thread, as events can be posted to specific threads rather than processes.

For the most part I would recommend not calling any SDL functions from anything other than the main thread apart from ones that don't operate on shared state.